# How can I replace the default Swift toolchain in XCode with the github code built locally?

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with using the open source version within the command line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode as of v7.3 has a "Toolchains" item in its application menu:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode menu showing Toolchains item]

These are stored in /Library/Developer/Toolchains. If you've built the project such that it has the correct structure (it seems to be bundle-like, with an Info.plist) and it's visible in that directory, it should show up in Xcode and be usable there.

If you need a reference point, there are package installers on the swift.org site: https://swift.org/download